How to filter a list of (random) vertices by the distance between each of the two neighboring vertices?
Here's my problem background: I have a surface mesh and I have a list of vertices (these vertices are generated by intersect the surface mesh with another mesh, using CGAL) shown as blue dots as follows:


As the vertices are too close, I want to filter these vertices such that the remain vertices has a distance of roughly the target edge length(the first neighboring vertex that has a distance larger than  target edge length).
To get what I want , I think the first step should rearrange the vertices as these vertices are stored randomly in a vector; then calculate the distance between the ith vertex and i+1th vertex, and filter the vertices that are too close.  But I dont know how to implement these.
Or if you have a better algorithm, could you help me solve this issue.
I appreciate if anyone could solve it. Thank you.
I use C++ and CGAL to implement this

"But I dont know how to implement these." - but you just explained how it should be implemented, so not sure where the problem is. You also didn't post any code with attempted solution and encountered issues.

This looks like an example of mesh simplification, have you looked into CGAL's Triangulated Surface Mesh Simplification options? link
